# Data transfer rate to and from host to device

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have the following transfers happening:

Host to device: 62504KB
Device to Host: 187512KB (which is 3 times of memory transfered between host to device)

I am running on Kepler K20c and nvprof is returning the following:

```
======== Profiling result:  
 Time(%)      Time   Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name  
   68.86   73.59ms       3   24.53ms   24.50ms   24.57ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]  
   21.97   23.47ms       3    7.82ms     992ns   23.47ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]  
    9.17    9.80ms       3    3.27ms    2.93ms    3.84ms  void   cuda_multi_gemm_unif_kernel_small_r
```

Does the time to transfer the data bytes to and from the device look reasonable? The data transfer rate from the above is as follows:

Host to Device transfer: 2.5398 GB/s
Device to Host transfer: 2.4300 GB/s

The bandwidth test at https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples/blob/master/series/cuda-cpp/optimize-data-transfers/bandwidthtest.cu

yields the following results

```
Device: Tesla K20c  
Transfer size (MB): 16

Pageable transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 2.822440
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 1.961510

Pinned transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 5.867341
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 6.629257

======== Profiling result:
 Time(%)      Time   Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
  55.09   10.34ms       2    5.17ms    2.50ms    7.84ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
  44.91    8.43ms       2    4.21ms    2.80ms    5.63ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
```

Comment: How reasonable the numbers are will depend on the host you are using. What does the bandwidth test that ships in the toolkit examples report for DtoH and HtoD bandwidth?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. The results of the bandwidth test are included. Host CPU is AMD Opteron 6168 with 1.9GHz clock frequency. I was using pageable transfer. So the bandwidth seems reasonable for pageable transfer, though the DtoH in my program is slightly higher.

Comment: For H2D & D2H you should compare against a little less of PCI-express peak bandwidth: v1 4 GB/s (×16), v2 8 GB/s (×16), v3 15.75 GB/s (×16). So 2GB/s seems pretty low. Are you using Pinned memory + cudaMemcpyAsync ?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was previously doing pageable transfer. I changed that to pinned transfer now with cudaMemcpyAsync, and now bandwidth is about 6GB/s. I understand that's still pretty low. I will check the PCI-express details (which version and how many lanes) on my platform.

Comment: If your mainboard or GPU is PCI-express 2.0 then 6GB/s seems ok to me (more or less the 80% of the peak bandwidth).